# Git tip is behind of current branch, conflict

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I tried to make workaround for a failing driver, but eventually it turned out that wasnt needed. but now i seam unable to push my local version to master.
I'm the only one updating my branch, but when i tried to fix this, i made several versions and branches after it. I'd like to reject all other versions and go back to my (older) working local copy and push it to server.

but when i do i get:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags 
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

also it wants me to pull 2 updates (which i dont want to since my local version is the one that works). I'm also not able to "reset current branch to this commit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use git push -f, to force your branch onto the origin branch.